# Active Directory Notifications - how to tell if a change is a new user

Tags: c#, active-directory, notifications

I have AD notifications working fine, monitoring OUs for changes (using a change notifier from http://dunnry.com/blog/ImplementingChangeNotificationsInNET.aspx). When a new user is created though, two notifications are generated, and I'm having trouble telling the two apart. My assumption (dangerous I know) is that the user is first created, then modified, but I'm not convinced that's the case.

My initial thoughts were to use uSNCreated and uSNChanged, but they are different even on the first notification. Similarly, whenCreated, whenChanged and modifyTimeStamp are the same per result for the two entries.

Clearly there must be a way to do this, but I can't see any attribute that can uniquely identify the first notification from the second.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

usnChanged is based on a counter that is updated incrementally for each change to AD as long as you're talking to the same DC. For the your change data, you could take the later of the two and use that record. To determine if a record is new, you can just track the highest of any usnChanged you have seen from previously received changes and compare usnCreated to that. If usnCreated is greater it's a new record.

You could also use highestCommittedUSN from RootDSE as your stored value for comparisons, but that would require doing a separate query after completing your change notification processing.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work for me. I'm only monitoring one OU and changes could happen elsewhere in the AD that I don't care about.

Answer (score 0):

The two notifications are coming from AD creating the object and then setting the password for the User.

`uSNChanged` is the way to go here.  The higher value is the latest change.  The trick in .NET is translating that value without using the icky Active Ds COM library.

There are several questions that already cover managing the uSNChanged property in a .NET-friendly way:

- [How to read "uSNChanged" property using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958278/how-to-read-usnchanged-property-using-c-sharp)
- [How to change System.DirectoryEntry "uSNChanged" attribute value to an Int64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101022/how-to-change-system-directoryentry-usnchanged-attribute-value-to-an-int64)