# How to retrieve all AD object using the USNChanged property and HighestCommittedUsn C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to do some kind of AD sync using USNChanged and retrieve all of the objects using the USNChanged property, but the entire process sounds a bit cryptic to me.

I have a PowerShell code that basically does what I need, but I was wondering you if anyone can help me convert it into a C# code. I would appreciate the help.

PS Code:

```
$highestCommittedUSN = (Get-ADRootDSE -server $preferredDC -properties * | select-object -property highestCommittedUSN).highestCommittedUSN
$lowUSN = 0
$highUSN = 0
for ($i=1000; $i -le $highestCommittedUSN ; $i=$i+10000 ) {
    [system.gc]::Collect()
    $error.clear() 
    $highUSN=$i
    write-host "(&(usnChanged>=$lowUSN)(usnChanged<$highUSN))" 
    $adObjects = (Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(usnChanged>=$lowUSN)(usnChanged<=$highUSN))" -Server $preferredDC -Properties * -IncludeDeletedObjects)
    ($adObjects).count
    if ($error.count -lt 0) {
            for ($j=$lowUSN; $j -le 490767138; $j=$j+1 ) {
                ">>>  " + $j
                $adObjects = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(usnChanged=$j)" -Server "DCName" -Properties * -IncludeDeletedObjects
                $adObjects | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File -FilePath ff.json -Append

                if ($error.count -ge 1) {
                    "There is problem with this USN " + $j + " on " + $preferredDC | Out-File -FilePath badUSN.txt -Append
                    
                    $adObjects.distinguishedName

                    }
                $adObjects.distinguishedName
            }
        }
        $lowUSN=$highUSN
        $adObjects.distinguishedName       
        $adObjects = $null
        $error.clear()
    }
```

I did found a similar question here : [How to read "uSNChanged" property using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958278/how-to-read-usnchanged-property-using-c-sharp) , but I'm not sure if I can use that answer.